# django-allauth connect with facebook

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I got my application up and running, integrated with facebook login.
Nevertheless, what is annoying me is that when I am connecting with facebook, it redirects me to www.facebook.com where I must enter my facebook password. Afterwards, I get redirected to homepage.

Can't I simply connect to facebook without redirecting to fb and asking for password? It is the behaviour I have seen to other sites where I am loging in with my facebook account. I am not prompted to introduce the password.

Is there any setup that I am missing?

Comment: Are you logged in in Facebook when you do this?

Comment: Yes, with cookies enabled. I guess this has something to do with some configuration inside developers.facebook??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably has set the auth_type param to 'reauthenticate' that makes facebook to asks the person to re-authenticate unconditionally.
Try to remove this param from your SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS setting:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email',],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {}, # Leave this empty
        'METHOD': 'oauth2'
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: yep, this was the problem. I've figured it out in the meantime. But thanks for your answer anyway